# Collect data with ajax call

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, click

I am trying to collect click events using ajax call. I don't care about the response which returned by the ajax. But the problem is when I click on anchor tag to navigate to another page, it is not happening until the ajax request completes.

any ideas on how to avoid this and do both the actions simultaneously?

here is my code

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/nextpage.html" onClick="javascript: fnRecordClick()">Click to next page</a>

function fnRecordClick(){
       return $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/click-event.php', 
            data:'event=clicked', 
            success:function(result)
            {                   

            }
        });
}
```